# First call to Snowflake from .NET Connector is very slow

Tags: c#, .net, http, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am currently checking the latency when connecting to Snowflake from the [Snowflake Connector for .NET library](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net). I have noticed that the first call when running the console application is some form of a "cold start", where it usually takes ~1 sec to connect for this call, compared to ~70 ms for subsequent calls. The graph below shows this clearer.

[image]

My question is: why is this?

I have tried checking the code in the snowflake connector module, but the trail seems to end with an HTTP call: `var response = await Snowflake.Data.Core.HttpUtil.getHttpClient().SendAsync(request, linkedCts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);`. I presume that the initial latency could have something to do with how HTTP works, but I don't know if that's true. Anyways, I think my webapp won't be affected by this initial delay, since it's server based - and my tests for this scenario shows that the delay only affects the first REST call, not the subsequent ones.

Oh, and here's the code I'm running to check the delay (with for loops and stuff omitted):

```
Stopwatch latencyConnectionWatch;
using (Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbConnection conn = new Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbConnection())
{
    conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    latencyConnectionWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    conn.Open();
    latencyConnectionWatch.Stop();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: You may have already solved this, but this could be the latency of the Snowflake compute warehouse starting up rather than the dot net connector latency.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like this has got to do with the HTTPS protocol rather than the module.